# custom error handling without try/except in php Slim framework

Tags: php, api, rest, slim

Using php and the Slim Framework, is there a way I can set up the error-handler so my custom Exceptions  that can automatically trigger the desired HTTP response, without forcing me to catch all the different exception types?

I know such examples from my projects with [python Flask](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/errors.html), but not the php equivalent.

For example, regardless where the exception is thrown in the code, I want my custom BadCustomerDataException() to trigger a HTTP 400 response, and the WaitingForResourceException() to trigger a 423 response, and the FaultyServerIsDeadAgainException() to trigger a 500 response.

Currently I'm using Slim version 3, with a planned update to version 4.

Comment: Which version of Slim are you using?

Comment: You want a custom error handling middleware, right? http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/middleware/error-handling.html

Comment: In Slim 4 you can add a custom error handler to the ErrorMiddleware, or you add your own Middleware before the ErrorMiddleware to catch and map your own Execptions: [Example](https://odan.github.io/2020/05/27/slim4-error-handling.html#catching-404-not-found-errors)

Comment: @odan. Thanks, your blog example with the HttpNotFoundException was exactly what I needed. Can you paste it in as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Slim 4 you can add a custom [error handler](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/middleware/error-handling.html) to the ErrorMiddleware. You can also add your own Middleware before the ErrorMiddleware to catch and map your own exceptions:

**Example**

```php
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;
use Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException;
use Slim\Middleware\ErrorMiddleware;
use Slim\Psr7\Response;
// ...

// HttpNotFound Middleware
$app->add(function (
    ServerRequestInterface $request, 
    RequestHandlerInterface $handler
    ) {
    try {
        return $handler->handle($request);
    } catch (HttpNotFoundException $httpException) {
        $response = (new Response())->withStatus(404);
        $response->getBody()->write('404 Not found');

        return $response;
    }
});

$app->add(ErrorMiddleware::class);
```

[Source](https://odan.github.io/2020/05/27/slim4-error-handling.html#catching-404-not-found-errors)